# How to check if a record exist ina database .. if it exist just increment qty (laravel)?

Tags: mysql, angular, laravel-8

**So im working on my project Laravel and angular ... now As I send cartItem from angular i want it to be checked in the backend if it exist then just increment qty else just insert**

Comment: you can do it using eloquent ORM, I can't answer your question more than that because you didn't provide more details. did you try to use eloquent and you got an error please share it with us

Comment: I have not tried anything yet but all i want to do is to make sure if a user add to cart the same product twice , then only the quantity is to be updated on the cart table

Comment: Hey, Please try it yourself if you got an error please post it here :)